# Querying on an array of objects without using RHS as a reference in Mongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongodb-query

The Mongo Collection Looks like Below :

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b693cbc032ee2fbb1d097f9"),
        "name" : "PersonName1",
        "email" : "dfgdfg@gmail.com",
        "phone" : "46756456",
        "address" : [
                {
                        "Home" : "Home 1 person1"
                },
                {
                        "Work" : "Work1 person 1"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b6943b0032ee2fbb1d097fa"),
        "name" : "PersoneName2",
        "email" : "dfgdsfgdfg@gmail.com",
        "phone" : "45645643",
        "address" : [
                {
                        "Home" : "Address of Home"
                },
                {
                        "Work" : "Address of Office"
                }
        ]
}
```

Performing the below query on the above collection

```
db.subdocs.find({},{"address":{$elemMatch:{"Home":1}}});
```

The output of above query only returns the object ids:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b693cbc032ee2fbb1d097f9") },

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6943b0032ee2fbb1d097fa") }
```

How do I get it to display both the Home addresses from my collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**`$exists`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query element operator with [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection to find whether the  key is exists in the array or not

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  address: {
    $elemMatch: {
      Home: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6k-ejzVPqUA)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about projection really doesn't match,
your query try find `address.Home = 1` and you need items those contain `address.Home` (`Home` exists)

then, just perform query...

```
db.subdocs.find({},{"address": { $elemMatch: { "Home" : { $exists: true } } } );
```

or if you need Home contains something

```
db.subdocs.find({},{"address": { $elemMatch: { "Home" : { $regex: "person" } } } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection("subdocs").find({
    address: {
        $elemMatch: {
            Home: {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    'address.$.Home': 1
})
```